Error de despliegue en Render de Api
Quiero realizar el despliegue de mi Api pero al realizarlo en Render me arroja este error
❌ Error connecting to the database: MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:27017
    at _handleConnectionErrors (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:896:11)
    at NativeConnection.openUri (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:847:11) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { '0.0.0.0:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined

Desde mi conexion a la base de datos en Mongo tengo esto
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/taskstraker')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/api-taskstraker')

    .then(() => console.log(' Database is Connected'))
    .catch(err => console.error('❌ Error connecting to the database:', err))

Como pueden ver intenté con las dos rutas diferentes y no conecta directamente a mi base datos en mongo

No puedo añadir comentarios, pero creo con el contexto que das. Deployaste tu api en render web services. Y tu api esta intentando conectarse a “localhost”. En tu equipo local funciona por que debes tener mongo instalado a lo que veo, pero en render necesitarias conectarte a una bd de mongo con acceso a intenet. Puedes probar utilizando la versión gratuita de mongo atlas y utilizar la cadena de conexión que ellos te dan para tener acceso a la bd de mongo. O en dado caso tener tu propio servidor de mongo montado en algun otro  hosting y que este este accesible desde el internet.
